# virsh attach-disk not working for iso file driver

Tags: virsh

Does anyone have any idea why I can't get this working.

I have a windows7 guest vm installed with virt-install on a bridge.  Windows 7 or 10 cannot get a drive for the network installed.
Following this thread [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270092/how-to-make-windows-guest-running-on-qemu-kvm-obtain-ip-address-from-physical-ro)

I download this iso and want to mount this so that the guest can see it.  I have been trying different things for over an hour.  nothing is working on my machine I am always getting

error: Failed to attach disk
error: unsupported configuration: unsupported driver name 'file' for disk 'hdc'

I have tried generally

```
attach-disk win7 /tmp/virtio-win-0.1.185.iso hdc --driver file --type cdrom --mode readonly
```

The above I have tried SEVERAL different ways and I end up with the same results.  I tried other ways like building an XML file and I always end up with an error or the sorts.  Everywhere online points to a simply command like this, so I am clearly doing something wrong.

Can someone point to me what is going on?

I also copied the xml snippet from another guest in the xml like so :

```
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/tmp/virtio-win-0.1.185.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
```

This time my guest accepted it with no warning but even on reboot I do not see something showing if I vnc into the windows vm.  I am at a loss...

Comment: Why are you trying to use IDE? A KVM virtual machine usually doesn't even have an IDE bus, as that was obsolete many years ago.

Comment: @MichaelHampton
I tried using example straight from the RH website
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/virtualization/sect-virtualization-virtualized_block_devices-add_a_virtualized_cd_rom_or_dvd_device_to_a_guest

I've also tried many other ways.  All I want to do is attach an ISO that should hold drivers for the network card for windows so I can get an IP.

from the link above this is the iso
https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/archive-virtio/virtio-win-0.1.185-2/virtio-win.iso

Comment: Why are you using obsolete documentation, then? What Linux distribution is this? What is your virtual machine configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did not assume using RH's official documentation would have been obsolete, and if you search online there is still lots of content about attaching via cdrom.

I did however try another way by attaching a shared img using qemu-img, but once I attach it to the windows guest it keeps wanting to initialize and fmt it.  I am simply trying to put some files on this image, attach it to the gust to fetch them and install NIC drivers for windows.
another linux guest can see the image w fdisk, but just can't mount getting wrong fs type
I am Centos7

Comment: You're reading RHEL 5 documentation, from 2007! Not a current distro version. So what Linux distribution is this? What is your virtual machine configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton
wow, thank you for pointing that out. I must have let my frustration get the best of me while looking for a fix. my config is Centos7, libvirt 4.5.0 its on a bridge so I can get IP from DHCP but the vm windows can't get NIC installed the string I did for install virt-install --name=win7 --os-type=windows --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/win7.img,size=20 --cdrom=/mnt/FTP/appz/MicrosoftOS/Win\ 7\ rars_FireBall/W7EER1x64.iso --graphics vnc -w bridge=br0,model=virtio --ram=1024 --vcpus=2 I just want to load files on this windows that apparently will help me install the drivers